# nw.js: How do I build a file dialog to open a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nw.js

My app is built with a placeholder where a file is read directly when "load" is clicked.

```
<button id="loadbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="showTheFile()">Load</button></a>
```

`showthefile()` does some stuff and then makes a call to...

```
var keyMapLoc = '\\path\\to\\file.txt';
function readKeys(ffile) {
// read the keyfile
    var ffile = ffile || keyMapLoc;
    return fs.readFileSync(ffile, 'utf8');
}
```

This reads the file into the app where it is parsed, yotta yotta.

[I followed these instructions](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/File-dialogs) and used the demo. The file dialog pops as soon as the app is opened, which I get.

```
<html>
<body>
<input style="display:none;" id="fileDialog" type="file" />
<script>
  function chooseFile(name) {
    var chooser = document.querySelector(name);
    chooser.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
      console.log(this.value);
    }, false);

    chooser.click();  
  }
  chooseFile('#fileDialog');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, even though I understand how to make a file dialog pop and I understand how to read/parse a file, I'm having a hard time working this very abstract example into my existing nwjs app.

Based on the above sample of my app, how should I blend in the demo so that the "load" button operates as expected for loading a file?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide your code, I'll go off the demo. What you need to do
is trigger the `click` event of the file input element and then upon a
`change` event, call `readKeys()`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input style="display:none;" id="fileDialog" type="file"/>

<button id="loadButton" type="button" class="btn btn-success"
        onclick="showTheFile()">Load</button>

<script>
    var fs = require('fs');
    var keyMapLoc = '\\path\\to\\file.txt';
    var chooser = document.querySelector("#fileDialog");

    // Set up the file chooser for the on change event
    chooser.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
        // When we reach this point, it means the user has selected a file,
        // so invoke readKeys().
        // this.value contains the path to the selected file
        console.log(readKeys(this.value));
    }, false); 

    function showTheFile() {
        // Trigger click event on the chooser, this will bring up the
        // dialog
        chooser.click()
    }

    function readKeys(ffile) {
        var ffile = ffile || keyMapLoc;
        return fs.readFileSync(ffile, 'utf8');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```